# dynamic textboxes on dropdown's selectedindex

Tags: asp.net

I want to create 5 text boxes created on drop down selected index change and 4 text boxes created if dropdown index is 4. dropdown is inside asp.net updatepanel. There is a button as well inside update panel. When user will click that button, whatever is typed in textboxes, is shown on label.

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this work

```
    <div>

</div><asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"><asp:ListItem Value="1">one </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="2">Two </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="3">Three </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="4">Four</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
 <br />
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="fectchText" onclick="Button2_Click" />
    <br />

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
```

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (ViewState["mode"].ToString() == "1")
            createTextbox();
        ViewState.Add("mode", "1");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState.Add("mode", "0");
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createTextbox();
}

public void createTextbox()
{
    int noOftextbox = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < noOftextbox; i++)
    {
        TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
        txtbox.ID = "txt" + i;
        txtbox.Visible = true;
        txtbox.Height = 30;
        txtbox.Width = 100;
        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(txtbox);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtbox);
     }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nocount=    Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
    for (int count = 0; count <= nocount-1 ; count++)
    {
     TextBox txtRead = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("txt" + (count));
     Label1.Text += txtRead.Text+"-";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.....

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ddlTest.SelectedIndex; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
```

Change ddlTest.SelectedIndex to your loop condition.....

Comment: How can I access the values user will type in these textboxes and also these controls (dropdownlist and dynamic textboxes) need to be inside ajax updatepanel

Answer (score 0):

Hers the solution create txtbox inside updatepanel

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False">
 <asp:ListItem Value="1">one </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="2">Two </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="3">Three </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="4">Four</asp:ListItem>


    </asp:DropDownList>
 <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>



</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int noOftextbox =Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);

    for (int i = 0; i < noOftextbox; i++)
    {
        TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
        txtbox.ID = i.ToString();
        txtbox.Visible = true;
        txtbox.Height = 30;
        txtbox.Width = 100;
        txtbox.Text = "txt" + i.ToString();
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtbox);
        //UpdatePanel1.Controls.Add(txtbox);
        //UpdatePanel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to get the values that user will type ?

Comment: enter value inside the  txt (runtime created) on label ??

Comment: I mean user will type anything in these dynamic textboxes, and there will be another button and label. user can click that button and values types in these dynamic textboxes should appear on label

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this...

```
//Add Control into Panel 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
        txt.Text = "this is text:" + i.ToString();
        pnlTest.Controls.Add(txt);
    }

    //Fetch Value from Panel
    for (int i = 0; i < pnlTest.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        string val = ((TextBox)pnlTest.Controls[i]).Text;
    }
```

First loop for add dynamic control into panel and another loop for fetch value from control....

Comment: Hi Manoj: It doesnt work inside updatepanel because updatepanel stops postbacks

Comment: Hi...
Please try this should be work on it because i have also done it in my application...
you may miss something there.